# Printing content after the end of all pages

Tags: css, xslt

I am generating html using XSL at the runtime. My task is to print signature section after all the data is printed. I am printing data like this:
Customer 1 data 
Customer 2 data 
Customer 3 data 
Customer 4 data 
Customer 5 data 
Owner's Signature
Each customer data has id, name, address, etc., upto 5 details per customer.
At the end of all customer data I need to print Owner's signature section.
Right now the customer data is running till 3 pages, and owner section is printing in the first page only. But i need owners signature at the end of the 3 pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a simple example how to produce some wanted output at the end of processing everything else**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:apply-templates/>

     Signature:
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="customer">
  Customer <xsl:value-of select="position()"/> data
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
 <customer/>
 <customer/>
 <customer/>
 <customer/>
 <customer/>
</t>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
  Customer 1 data

  Customer 2 data

  Customer 3 data

  Customer 4 data

  Customer 5 data


     Signature:
```

**Explanation**:

All processing (disregarding non-element top nodes (it is safe to assume that no such exist) ) is captured in this template:

```
 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:apply-templates/>

     Signature:
 </xsl:template>
```

Because the string `"Signature:"` is physically the very last in the template, and because an XML document only has a single top element node and this template is selected only once, this guarantees that the string `"Signature:"` is the last output produced by the transformation.

Comment: @sans481: I updated my answer with the requested explanation.

Comment: What if I have to print customer 2's signature at the end? After all the customer data..

Comment: This is a related, but different question. Please, ask a new question. The answer is again very straight-forward. As for the current question, it is completely answered. Unaccepting the answer doesn't change this fact.